# question mark replaces citations in pdf

Tags: citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

how to replace [?] with the actual numerical citation. 
I'm trying to create a bilbiography in Winshell from a database (.bib file). Within the bib file, I click on pdflatex, then bibtek, then pdflatex twice, and then pdf. 
My pdf shows [?] for numerical citations and no complete bibliography.
Please help!

Comment: Hi Keith, the question mark alone is only an indicator that something went wrong but not enough to diagnose the problem. Try to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number; especially at Paul Stanley's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/510).

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{headings}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\subsection 
\subsubsection 
Text with \cite{hatcher2008}

\subsection


\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}

Comment: @article{hatcher2008,
 author               = {Hatcher, H. and Planalp, R. and Cho, J. and Torti, FM and Torti, SV},
 journal              = {Cellular and Molecular Life Sciences},
 number               = {11},
 pages                = {1631--1652},
 publisher            = {Springer},
 title                = {Curcumin: from ancient medicine to current clinical trials},
 volume               = {65},
 year                 = {2008},
 }

Comment: @Keith: You can edit your question; please include the comments there.

Comment: not sure how to edit question. If someone could provide additional instruction beyond the edit tab, I'd gladly reformat the question!

Comment: @Keith: We have a [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq); you even get a nice [badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/109/analytical) after you've read it. `:-)`